# Why do we need ".\" in Regex substitution s/.\{1}$//

Tags: regex

This expression is to delete the last character in a line.

Comment: You should provide more context, there are different regex engines with different behaviors: for example, using `sed` the command to remove the last character is: `sed "s/.$//"`

Answer (score 1):

The grouping is not `.\` but `\{`. That's just how the syntax is. It tells the reggex engine that `{` is supposed to be treated as a special character.

Otherwise it would try to match the character `{` literally.

---

However, the whole `{1}` is unnecessary because `.` already implies matching a single character.

Comment: Then why the other brace doesn't require escaping as well?

Comment: Maybe because the engine can infer that the following `}` is special. I don't know though. http://www.vimregex.com/#Non-Greedy